# How to refactor multiple if-else statements in Python into a function?

Tags: python, function

I have a function like this:

```
def helper() -> dict:

    start_date_lst = get_start_date_lst()        
    end_date_lst = get_end_date()               

    answer_dict = {}
    if date in start_date_lst:
        answer_dict['event'] = "start_date"
        answer_dict["date"] = "date1"
    elif date in end_date_lst:
        answer_dict['event'] = "end_date"
        answer_dict["date"] = "date2"     

    return answer_dict
```

What I want to achieve is to **create a new function** strictly for the `if-else` block of code. How can I do this?

For instance, in this [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/dictionary-as-an-alternative-to-if-else-76fe57a1e4af) a function handles the if-else statements.

```
def operations(operator, x, y):
    if operator == 'add':
        return x + y
    elif operator == 'sub':
        return x - y
    elif operator == 'mul':
        return x * y
    elif operator == 'div':
        return x / y
```

becomes

```
def operations(operator, x, y):
    return {
        'add': lambda: x+y,
        'sub': lambda: x-y,
        'mul': lambda: x*y,
        'div': lambda: x/y,
    }.get(operator, lambda: 'Not a valid operation')()
```

I need to do this because I still need to add multiple `elif` statements.

**Edit:**
@M Λ I K pointed out that I do not need the extra function. So I solved my question by leaving my original function as it was :).

Comment: What do you exactly mean with create a new function?

Comment: Well, what parameters do you think the function should have (what information does it need in order to perform the task)? What do you think it should return, if anything? (Should it modify an existing, passed-in `dict`? Or create an return a new one? Or something else?) What generally should it do exactly? It's not clear *what help you need*, because clearly you already know how to write a function. Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum, and we thus cannot help you *design* your code.

Comment: What is `date`? Hopefully not a global variable!

Comment: @MΛIK I mean a function I can call inside my `helper` function that handles the if-else logic.

Comment: @PercySherlock You can simply create another function and call it inside your current function. But haven't got the point why you need one? As Karl already said, which returns do you want to have, which parameters etc.

Comment: I think you already gave the answer yourself. Just change the example function in order to work for your own function.

Comment: @user2390182 I have made a correction.

Comment: Not one that clears up the origins of `date` :)

Comment: @MΛIK that's what I could not figure out. Could you help?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel the goal is to move the if-else to a new function and call it in my helper function because the original code I'm implementing is getting long as there are multiple if-else statements. I wanted to see if I could reduce the lines of codes.

Comment: @PercySherlock I will post a answer and delete it afterwards. Just get an idea of how it could work